# What is the best way to use a filtered version of a DataTable?

Tags: .net, datatable, architecture, ado.net, dataview

I have a `DataSet` containing 4 `DataTable`s, say `dt1`, `dt2`, `dt3`, `dt4`. I also have 3 `DataRelation`s like this:

```
|Parent|Child|
|  d1  |  d2 |
|  d2  |  d3 |
|  d2  |  d4 |
```

My `MasterClass` passes this `DataSet` to several classes, each class needs to perform different actions using the `DataSet`. However, before passing the `DataSet`, `MasterClass` needs to perform a filter on `dt1`, as each class needs to work with the filtered version of `dt1`. Note that I can't update `dt1`, as I need to perform different filters on the same `DataTable`. In the picture below, I try to visualize the structure:

[image: The Architecture]

**My question is**: What is the best way to pass the filtered `dt1` to `Class A..B`?

The first solution that I thought of, was to create a copy of `dt1` in my `DataSet`, and store the filtered version in it, say `FilteredDt1`, however, I don't want to have redundant data / `DataRow`s in memory.

From what I've read in docs from Microsoft, I think that I can do better with the help of a `DataView`, in a way that I pass the `DataView` as a second parameter to the classes, but I didn't get how I can do it, also from **software architecture** point of view.

**Problems** that I met:

- Is it still possible to use the `DataRelation`s, if I use a `DataView`?
- Is it possible to run a join on the `DataView` and a `DataTable`?

*I am rather new to `ADO.NET`, and I'd appretiate it very much, if you correct me, if there are any mistakes / incorrect assumptions in my question.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use linq:

```
var filtered1 = MyDataSet.Tables["d1"].Rows.OfType<DataRow>()
                .Where(r => r["Column"] = value);

var filtered2 = MyDataSet.Tables["d1"].Rows.OfType<DataRow>()
                .Where(r => r["OtherColumn"] = differentValue);
```

Now `filtered1` will return an `IEnumerable<DataRow>` where `Column = value`,
And `filtered2` will return an `IEnumerable<DataRow>` where `OtherColumn = differentValue`,

And your original data table is left unchanged.

Note that I had to use the `OfType` extension method before I could use the `Where` extension method, since the `Rows` property is of type `DataRowCollection` that does not implement the generic `IEnumerable<T>` interface, only the not-generic `IEnumerable` (and `ICollection`) interface.

**Update:**

Looking for a way to return a filtered data table without changing the source data table I came across the [`AsEnumerable`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatableextensions.asenumerable(v=vs.110).aspx) extension method for the `DataTable` class, which returns an `IEnumerable<DataRow>()`, so my suggestion can be simplified to `...MyDataSet.Tables["d1"].AsEnumerable().Where...`.

Also, I've found a way for you to create copies of the data table with only the filtered rows. What you do is use the [`DataView` constructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8sd1cd0a(v=vs.110).aspx) that accepts `DataTable`, `RowFilter`, `Sort`, and `DataViewRowState`, and then call it's [`ToTable`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a8ycds2f(v=vs.110).aspx) method to return a new data table.
Please note that this will create new copies for the data rows in memory, since a `DataRow` can only belong to a single `DataTable`.

However, Please note I would advise working with `IEnumerable<T>`, where `T` is specific types you creates as [DTO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_transfer_object)s rather then working with directly `DataTable`. That will make your life much safer and easier.

Comment: Aren't the filtered collections (`filtered1` and `filtered2`) redundant data in memory? I mean do they only refer to the original `DataRow`s or are they copies of them? And is it still possible to use the `DataRelation`s?

Comment: As far as I know, they refer to the original data rows. You can't use them with `DataRelation` instances, since `DataRelation` only knows how to work with `DataTable` instances.

Comment: Thank you very much! I will try it out, to see if it's better to work with `RowCollection` rather than a `DataTable`.

Comment: I cannot use `IEnumerable<T>` with specific typs because of performance and memory reasons. About `DataView` and `Totable` method, it is actually not different from creating another `DataTable`.

Comment: Anyways, I used `IEnumerable<DataRow>`. As you said I don't have redundant objects in memory like this. However, I cannot use the `DataRelation`s, which I think is not a big deal. I think I've thought a bit more complex than required ;)